# Getting FB profile photo with Shrine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, shrine

I'm using Devise for authentication in my project and I'm having troubles getting the image when logging through FB with Shrine gem.

I have standard devise method to get data from Omniauth provider in user model:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      # Standard version
      user.avatar = auth.info.image
      # For Google:
      # user.avatar_remote_url = auth.info.image
    end
  end
```

The commented line works for logging with Google and sets the image properly as `auth.info.image` returns link which, when pasted into browser, opens an image in the browser. For FB however, this line of code results in failing to persist the user - in case of FB `auth.info.image` returns a link which downloads the file directly to HDD if pasted into browser.

The standard version on the other hand results in error `809: unexpected token at 'http://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/xxxxxxxxxxx/picture?access_token=xxxxxxxx` when trying to sign up.

In another project I'm successfully getting the image from fb the standard way but there I'm using paperclip. I definitely have a proper set up set for Shrine and user prepared for the data (double checked it, and also - it works for Google oauth with the _remote_url helper) - I'm not sure though how to properly process the data received from FB with Shrine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under https://github.com/simi/omniauth-facebook#configuring it states that default configuration for provider is `secure_image_url: true` which doesn't seem to be the case though. The answer was to add `secure_image_url: true` to my provider hash for Facebook, it then returns https link instead of http via `auth.info.image` which can be assigned to `user.avatar_remote_url`. Question can be closed.